# Laravel Echo private vs join, when using join, listen events doesn't work

Tags: laravel, join, private, pusher, laravel-echo

I'm using Laravel Echo with Pusher to make a realtime chat app.

On the client side, I was instantiating Laravel Echo like this :

```
Echo
.private('chat')
.listen('MessageSentEvent', function(event) {
    ...
});
```

But then I needed to use the here(), joining() and leaving() methods.

I found out that I need to use `Echo.join()` instead of private.

So I changed to this :

```
Echo
.join('chat')
.here((users) => {
    ...
})
.joining((user) => {
    ...
})
.leaving((user) => {
    ...
})
.listen('MessageSentEvent', function(event) {
    ...
});
```

Now Laravel Echo doesn't receive any event with the listen.

If I change back to `Echo.private()` then I receive the events but the methods are not existing...

Don't know what to do here. Is it not possible to have both ?

Comment: Can you please show us how you're broadcasting the message from within Laravel. typically `private` broadcasts are done with `new PrivateChannel()` (unless it's a presence channel), bu that won't work for a non-private channel.

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy, I just found out that I was still returning a PrivateChannel. I tried using a PresenceChannel and join and the others methods works. Hope this is still as secure as the PrivateChannel ?!

Comment: They work the same, but a Presence Channel is intended for multiple users. Make sure you confirm they can access that channel.

Comment: I have the same problem